# PyAutoGui module missing from Executable file made with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller, pyautogui

I've created a program that uses Tkinter and PyAutoGui as dependencies and I want to create a executable file that can run independently on a separate machine.  I run run the code;

```
pyinstaller C:\Users\ctracey\MyScripts\packagePromos.py
```

The cmd run fine and I get a successful compile reading this;

```
88 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
88 INFO: Python: 3.7.1
88 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
91 INFO: wrote C:\Users\ctracey\packagePromos.spec
95 INFO: UPX is not available.
96 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\ctracey\\MyScripts', 'C:\\Users\\ctracey']
97 INFO: checking Analysis
225 INFO: checking PYZ
241 INFO: checking PKG
252 INFO: Building because toc changed
252 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
290 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg    completed successfully.
292 INFO: Bootloader    c:\users\ctracey\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
292 INFO: checking EXE
304 INFO: Building because name changed
304 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
305 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\ctracey\build\packagePromos\packagePromos.exe
317 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
324 INFO: checking COLLECT
336 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
3439 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

but when I go to run the program a CMD windows pops up and closes briefly showing this short message;

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "packagePromos.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'pyautogui'
[25004] failed to execute script packagePromos
```

I know simply this means that the PyAutoGui module/dependecy was not compiled in the Executable file/folder but what I want to know is why and how do I fix it so it will be?

I've installed Python, PyAutoGUI, Image with Pip and updated them accordingly to the latest version and still no luck.

Comment: maybe pyautogui does not support python 3.7.1

Comment: That's a very good point which I somehow did think of. The official documentation state only platforms 3.4, 3.3, 3.2, 3.1, 2.7, 2.6, 2.5 have been tested.

Will test this and let you know. Thanks

Comment: PyautoGUI is perfectly being compiled with Pyinstaller using python 2.7.15.

Comment: `pyautogui` works fine with Python 3.7.0... I'm not sure the likelihood of a micro version increment affecting support...

Comment: [`pyautogui` is not listed in the supported packages list](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages).  Perhaps it's a simple matter of it not being supported at all by `pyinstaller`.  `pywinauto` however is listed though, perhaps a viable alternative?

Comment: That would make the most sense that `pyautogui` not being supported by the `pyinstaller` but I read so many people on here and other sites compiling .exe tho. It'd be a big set back for me if that's the case as this is my first program and just getting my bearings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the library to be imported.

For example:

```py
pyinstaller main.py --hiddenimport = pyautogui
```